# How can I fix the PlatformException with Google Sign-In on iOS in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to add Google Singin to my project. Web and Android is working fine, but on ios this trows.

```
if (errorCode is String && (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining) { throw PlatformException(code: errorCode)
      throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String?, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace)
    } else {
      throw const FormatException('Invalid envelope');
    }
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
• Flutter version 3.10.2 on channel stable at /Users/furkanbora/code/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 9cd3d0d9ff (7 days ago), 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
• Engine revision 90fa3ae28f
• Dart version 3.0.2
• DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/furkanbora/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E222b
• CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
• VS Code at /Users/furkanbora/Desktop/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 14 (mobile) • 84FCB138-5C07-4504-8FB8-407559031F6C • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)    • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

For the backend I use Firebase.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSHhK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DECow.png)

I am only getting this problem on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you properly follow the instructions as per Google's Firebase for iOS setup documentation? It is easy to miss downloading the GoogleService-Info.plist file and moving it into your project's `ios/Runner` folder.

An example would be: `C:\Users\USERNAME\FLUTTER_PROJECT_DIRECTORY\ios\Runner`
you should move the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file you downloaded from your Firebase Project's page to here.

You can find the download button for `GoogleService-Info.plist` in your project's SDK setup and configuration tab for iOS. The button is visible in the first screenshot you provided.

Hope that helps!

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem with the location of the GoogleService-Info.plist file, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using the permission_handler package? 
By doing a quick search, I found multiple cases of people getting an error similar to the one you provided, because they have not properly requested Permissions on iOS. 

If you can provide detailed information, I'll be happy to help! With the information you provided, we are forced to take blank shots.